# How can I mirror a movie and play it in reverse?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have been playing with [QMovie](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMovie.html) a bit trying to mirror a movie as well as play it in reverse.
For the mirroring bit I tried assigning a negative width to no avail. Since [QImage](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html) does offer facilities for this I had hoped [QMovie](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMovie.html) would do the same.
There don't seem to be any facilities in the [QMovie](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMovie.html) object for those things, so I'm wondering if I could manipulate the [QIODevice](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QIODevice.html) to the [QMovie](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMovie.html) object instead to achieve this, but this is completely new territory for me and I don't see anything obvious in the documentation that would achieve mirroring or playing in reverse.
The code example to start with would be the same as on the PySide page:

```
label = QLabel()
movie = QMovie("animations/fire.gif")
label.setMovie(movie)
movie.start()
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QMovie` doesn't provide the methods to set the current image, so you have to use directly `QImageReader` to play it in reverse (using `QImageReader::jumpToImage()`). This is not very easy bacause the delay between a frame and the next can change, but however you can get it calling `QImageReader::nextImageDelay()`.

To display the movie, you can implement your own widget to draw the movie as you want.

In the `paintEvent()` you can set a transformation to the painter to get the mirror effect and than draw the current image of the movie.

Example:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.scale(-1, 1); // x-axis mirror
    //here maybe you must adjust the transformation to center and scale the movie.
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, currentImage);
}
```

To play the movie you have to set a timer that change the current image.

Example:

```
//you must create a timer in the constructor and connect it to this slot
void MyWidget::timeoutSlot()
{
    int currentImageIndex;
    //here you have to compute the image index
    imageReader.jumpToImage(currentImageIndex);
    currentImage = imageReader.read(); //maybe you want to read it only if the index is changed
    update();
}
```

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html) you can find an example of widget subclass, with timer and painter transformation

See also [QImageReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html), [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), [QWidget::paintEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent)

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like I need to re-implement QMovie altogether, shame. I will try your suggestions and see how far I get, thanks.

Comment: so I tried your suggestion and wrote my own widget using QImageReader. As a first test I hooked it up to a QSlider to drive the current frame of the animated gif, but whatever number I feed **QImageReader.jumpToImage**, subsequent calls to **read()** only ever read the next frame until the end is reached. So I can't control what frame to read at all at the moment

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the implementation of jumpToImage for GIF doesn't work. Maybe you can load and cache all the frames in a map and take the images from it in the timer slot (this can cause a large memory usage)

Comment: Ha, funny, I just tried exactly that a minute before reading your reply.
I needed to use cacheAll() on QMovie anyway to be able to scrub back and forth without delay, which is an important feature, so I just wrote a simple loop that repeatedly reads the image reader and stores the resulting QImages in a list. I'm sure this will make my memory consumption go through the roof eventually, but that might just be the price for what I'm after.
I just need to write equivalent methods to mimic all the other QMovie features I need now and hope that memory management doesn't become imposisble.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer. While it's not as straight forward as I had hoped, Fabio's suggestion certainly pointed me in the right direction.
Thanks Fabio.